# Offsetting a hash tag link to adjust for fixed header when typing url in browser in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, hyperlink

I wish to create a page that allows hash tags to jump to certain contents of the page.

e.g.

http://example.com/page1 is a normal page

http://example.com/page1#info will jump to the tag with id `#info`

This is default browser behaviour so no issue there.

The problem begins when I have a fixed browser header, as I need some extra offset so that the fixed header does not cover up the element.

For internal links on the page this is not an issue as I just use the following code:

```
var scrollOffset = 175;
$('a.tab-button[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var $target = $(targetId);
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));

    if( $target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.scrollTo(0, $target.offset().top - scrollOffset);
    }
})
```

where `scrollOffset` is the number of pixels I wish to offset it by.

However the issue lies when typing the url in the browser it self and clicking enter (as supposed to clicking a URL anchor tag on the page directly). Although it scrolls to the element correctly; there is no offset, between the browser window and the element, causing it to be hidden under the fixed navigation bar.

Note I am aware of the following technique already:

```
h2:before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -285px; 
  height: 285px; 
  visibility: hidden; 
}
```

and other CSS tricks in http://nicolasgallagher.com/jump-links-and-viewport-positioning/demo/

Therefore please give JS answers only please!!!

Comment: So per my understanding, issue is, when user types #tags, then page is loaded but page does not scrolls to section. If this is the case, you can write a load function which will read #tag from url and will trigger click function of necessary 'a' tag.

Comment: No it does scroll to the section. The issue is that there is no offset between the element and the browser window. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work.  The `gotoHash()` function is basically the same as your existing code, except it's within a timeout, which makes `event.preventDefault()` unnecessary. This also solves a problem when the function runs after document ready but before the browser has scrolled to a hash:

```js
location.hash = '#d3';  //used for demonstration purposes only

function gotoHash(id) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var $target = $(id),
        scrollOffset = 100,
        y = $target.offset().top - scrollOffset;

    if ($target.length) {
      window.scrollTo(0, y);
    }
  });
}

$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function() {
  gotoHash($(this).attr('href'));
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  gotoHash(location.hash);
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px verdana;
  margin: 100px 0px;
}
header {
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
div {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <a href="#d1">div 1</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#d2">div 2</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#d3">div 3</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#d4">div 4</a>
  <br>
</header>
<div id="d1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
<div id="d2">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
<div id="d3">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
<div id="d4">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```