# When I click an anchor on a navbar it takes me there, but part of the content is hidden by the navbar itself

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

So I saw some templates online that when you click on an anchor on the navbar, the page takes you to that section, and the divisions are perfectly aligned, meaning that what you see at the top of the page (obviously while ignoring the navbar), is the top of the division.

I tried to do this, but when I tried, some of the content is put behind the navbar, does anyone know how to fix this?

What I did to "solve" this problem was add padding to the section blocks, but it would look a lot better if it was perfectly aligned.

This is the template: https://startbootstrap.com/theme/freelancer

The HTML and JavaScript of the template is shown below (I can't upload the CSS because of the character limit), can someone please tell me which section of the code is doing this?

This is part of the HTML:

```
**<!-- Navigation-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary text-uppercase fixed-top" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler text-uppercase font-weight-bold bg-primary text-white rounded" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    Menu
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1"><a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1"><a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded" href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1"><a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Masthead-->
        <header class="masthead bg-primary text-white text-center">
            <div class="container d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
                <!-- Masthead Avatar Image-->
                <img class="masthead-avatar mb-5" src="assets/img/avataaars.svg" alt="..." />
                <!-- Masthead Heading-->
                <h1 class="masthead-heading text-uppercase mb-0">Start Bootstrap</h1>
                <!-- Icon Divider-->
                <div class="divider-custom divider-light">
                    <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
                    <div class="divider-custom-icon"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></div>
                    <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- Masthead Subheading-->
                <p class="masthead-subheading font-weight-light mb-0">Graphic Artist - Web Designer - Illustrator</p>
            </div>
        </header>
<!-- About Section-->
        <section class="page-section bg-primary text-white mb-0" id="about">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- About Section Heading-->
                <h2 class="page-section-heading text-center text-uppercase text-white">About</h2>
                <!-- Icon Divider-->
                <div class="divider-custom divider-light">
                    <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
                    <div class="divider-custom-icon"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></div>
                    <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- About Section Content-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 ms-auto"><p class="lead">Freelancer is a free bootstrap theme created by Start Bootstrap. The download includes the complete source files including HTML, CSS, and JavaScript as well as optional SASS stylesheets for easy customization.</p></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 me-auto"><p class="lead">You can create your own custom avatar for the masthead, change the icon in the dividers, and add your email address to the contact form to make it fully functional!</p></div>
                </div>
                <!-- About Section Button-->
                <div class="text-center mt-4">
                    <a class="btn btn-xl btn-outline-light" href="https://startbootstrap.com/theme/freelancer/">
                        <i class="fas fa-download me-2"></i>
                        Free Download!
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>**
```

And this is the JavaScript

```
    /*!
* Start Bootstrap - Freelancer v7.0.3 (https://startbootstrap.com/theme/freelancer)
* Copyright 2013-2021 Start Bootstrap
* Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-freelancer/blob/master/LICENSE)
*/
//
// Scripts
// 

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {

    // Navbar shrink function
    var navbarShrink = function () {
        const navbarCollapsible = document.body.querySelector('#mainNav');
        if (!navbarCollapsible) {
            return;
        }
        if (window.scrollY === 0) {
            navbarCollapsible.classList.remove('navbar-shrink')
        } else {
            navbarCollapsible.classList.add('navbar-shrink')
        }

    };

    // Shrink the navbar 
    navbarShrink();

    // Shrink the navbar when page is scrolled
    document.addEventListener('scroll', navbarShrink);

    // Activate Bootstrap scrollspy on the main nav element
    const mainNav = document.body.querySelector('#mainNav');
    if (mainNav) {
        new bootstrap.ScrollSpy(document.body, {
            target: '#mainNav',
            offset: 72,
        });
    };

    // Collapse responsive navbar when toggler is visible
    const navbarToggler = document.body.querySelector('.navbar-toggler');
    const responsiveNavItems = [].slice.call(
        document.querySelectorAll('#navbarResponsive .nav-link')
    );
    responsiveNavItems.map(function (responsiveNavItem) {
        responsiveNavItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (window.getComputedStyle(navbarToggler).display !== 'none') {
                navbarToggler.click();
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Here is a picture of the template, as we can see, the divisions are very clear because of their background color:

[image]

When I click on the portfolio on the navbar, it moves it down, at the top of the selected division:

[image]
When I do that on my HTML file, it takes me down to the selected section, but the top of that section is hidden by the navbar itself. Here is a picture of the section:

[image]
And here is a picture after I click on the anchor in the navbar, as we can see, it did take me to that section, but the title is hidden by the navbar itself, this does not happen in the template.

[image]

To solve this I simply added padding to the section, but it still does not look as good as the template

Comment: Can you please add a snippet with the same issue?

Comment: The files that I have are a mess because I've been copying and pasting from different templates that I've been finding online, so I'm not sure if it will be very helpful. Also, I have no idea if the issue is in the JavaScript, HTML, or CSS, which section should do you want me to show you?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot or short video of the issue ?

Comment: Okay, hang on one sec

Comment: Okay I uploaded some screenshots, hope they help

Comment: The issue is in the offset you are giving I think

Comment: can you please tell me the section of the code that does that on the template?

Comment: `target: '#mainNav', offset: 72` This place. Can you check by changing the value of offset ?

Comment: that doesn't seem to change the position where it moves

Comment: https://codepen.io/DeviceGucci/pen/JjNXWbg

I created this codepen link, if you can't view it please let me know, and hopefully that will help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Offsetting a hash tag link to adjust for fixed header when typing url in browser in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348329/offsetting-a-hash-tag-link-to-adjust-for-fixed-header-when-typing-url-in-browser)

Comment: No i haven't been able to do it, but does anyone know which part of the code of the template is responsible for that?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to create an offset for the size of fixed header.

Here are some solutions:

https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/

https://fellowtuts.com/html-css/offsetting-anchor-hash-tag-links-to-adjust-for-fixed-header/

Comment: Thank you, I will check it and update if I get it to work

Comment: I just can't get it to work, maybe because of the images or maybe some things override the solutions, do you know which section of the code does that on the template?

Comment: @DeviceGucci Could you create a [reproducible snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I understand your problem, but can't debug with partial code. Create a code snippet on codepen or something similar.

Comment: Does this link work? I have never used codepen so I am not sure if you will be able to view this

This is the template, I would like to know which part is responsible for the offset

https://codepen.io/DeviceGucci/pen/JjNXWbg

Comment: @DeviceGucci The codepen snippet you have shared seems to be working as you have intended.

Comment: yes, I would like to know which section of that code is responsible for the offset, my code is very bad because I've been copying and pasting a lot of sections of different templates, so it would be a lot harder to find the problem in my code

Answer (score 0):

it happened because the next page has no paddings from top so that is set by default as 0 you can add padding either from top of the content or you can also give bottom to your nave.

you can try it

```
.toppd{
   padding-top : 30px;
 }
```

add this class to your first `<section>` or `<div>` of your page

Comment: I do have paddings, however it is not the same as being taken to the exact place, I might just leave it with the padding in the meantime, but it does not look as good as the template

Answer (score -1):

You should use css z-index in this case.

```
navbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

negative value means it will be put behind. You can index many divs and other elements as you want with positiv number. This piece of CSS can send the navbar back.

Comment: This didn't do anything, it looks the same, but thank you for answering